# Receiving an unknown error in supply drop code

Tags: python

## Here is the code I am using, when I try to run the program it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    drop()
  omitted for privacy reasons, line 138, in drop
    print("here is your",gunrarity,item)
NameError: global name 'gunrarity' is not defined
```

.

```
import random
import time
def drop():
drop=random.randint(1,1000)
print("Possible drops:")
print("M16A4")
print("AK47")
print("M1911")
print("Scar-L")
print("AWM")
print("KRISS Vector")
print("Combat Knife")
print("AUG A1")
if 1<=drop<=200:
    item=("M16A4")
elif 201<=drop<=400:
    item=("AK47")
elif 401<=drop<=600:
    item=("Scar-L")
elif 601<=drop<=800:
    item=("M1911")
elif 801<=drop<=875:
    item=("AWM")
elif 876<=drop<=950:
    item=("KRISS Vector")
elif 951<=drop<=990:
    item=("Combat Knife")
else:
    item=("Desert Eagle")




        if item==("M16A4"):
            rarity1=random.randint(1,1000)

        if 1<=rarity1<=699:
            gunrarity=("Common")

        elif 700<=rarity1<=899:
            gunrarity=("Uncommon")

        else:
            gunrarity=("Epic")




        if item==("AK47"):
            rarity2=random.randint(1,1000)

            if 1<=rarity2<=699:
                gunrarity=("Common")

            elif 700<=rarity2<=899:
                        gunrarity=("Uncommon")

            else:
                    gunrarity==("Epic")




            if item==("Scar-L"):
                rarity3=random.randint(1,1000)

                if 1<=rarity3<=699:
                        gunrarity==("Common")

                elif 700<=rarity3<=899:
                        gunrarity==("Uncommon")

                else:
                        gunrarity==("Epic")





            if item==("M1911"):
                    rarity4=random.randint(1,1000)

                    if 1<=rarity4<=699:
                            gunrarity==("Common")

                    elif 700<=rarity4<=899:
                            gunrarity==("Uncommon")

                    else:
                            gunrarity==("Epic")


                    if item==("AWM"):
                        rarity5=random.randint(1,1000)

                    if 1<=rarity5<=699:
                            gunrarity==("Epic")

                    else:
                            gunrarity==("Rare")

                    if item==("KRISS Vector"):
                        rarity6=random.randint(1,1000)

                    if 1<=rarity6<=699:
                            gunrarity==("Epic")

                    elif 700<=rarity6<=989:
                                gunrarity==("Rare")

                    else:
                            gunrarity==("Exceedingly Rare!")

                    if item==("Combat Knife"):
                        rarity7=random.randint(1,1000)

                    if 1<=rarity7<=949:
                        gunrarity==("Exceedingly Rare!")

                    else:
                            gunrarity==("Insanely Rare!")

                    if item==("Desert Eagle"):
                        rarity8=random.randint(1,1000)

                    if 1<=rarity8<=949:
                        gunrarity==("Exceedingly Rare!")

                    else:
                            gunrarity==("Insanely Rare!")







print("here is your",gunrarity,item)
```

## it would be great if you could help me fams

Comment: totally a side note but I like your cs-go style :)

Comment: gunrarity isn't initialised to any value. If none of the conditions match, then gunrarity isn't defined. Hence, the error 'gunrarity' is not defined in the last line.

Comment: how can i fix this?

Comment: I'm not following your spacing structure but it looks like your print statement is in the global area rather than just the def drop() as result it doesn't know what gunrarity is.

Comment: i dont understand

Answer (score 0):

Simply write after function declaration this string:

```
gunrarity=0
```

like:

```
def drop():
    gunrarity=0
    drop=random.randint(1,1000)
    print("Possible drops:")
```

AND WRITE CODE CLEAR!!!
use 4 spaces as indentation